# Angular Material expansion panel open fired by radio button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a scenario where I'm trying to use a Material radio button click event to trigger the opening of an associated expansion panel with a `mat-accordion` control.

The ultimate goal is for the user to click on the radio button, showing the radio state as "checked" and opening the panel containing the selected radio button. Currently, the click event is properly setting the underlying `step` value, but the panel itself is not being expanded.

Here's the code for the accordion component:

```
<mat-accordion multi hideToggle>
  <mat-expansion-panel id="panel1" [expanded]="step === 0">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <mat-radio-button name="multi-accordion" id="set-step-0" (click)="setStep(0)">
          <span>Panel 1</span>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Panel 1 content
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel id="panel2" [expanded]="step === 1">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <mat-radio-button name="multi-accordion" id="set-step-1" (click)="setStep(1)">
          <span>Panel 2</span>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Panel 2 content
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel id="panel2" [expanded]="step === 2">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <mat-radio-button name="multi-accordion" id="set-step-2" (click)="setStep(2)">
          <span>Panel 3</span>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Panel 3 content
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Here's the .ts file that I'm using to do the work:

```
export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {
  step = -1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  setStep(index: number) {
    if (index == this.step) { return; }
    console.log('Step before setting index: ', this.step);
    this.step = index;
    console.log('Step after setting index: ', this.step);
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the value that's being set properly by the click event (as evidenced by the `console.log` statements) is not being picked up the binding on the `[expanded] ="step === n"` on the panel itself.

Comment: If others want to investigate, I prepared a StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ksqhqz). It looks like your property is right but some behavior from MatExpansionPanel modifies the attributes afterwards

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudDenoyelle, it *mostly* works. I seems like one of the attributes being modified includes the checked state of the radio button itself. Using your StackBlitz, you'll see that the associated radio button looks selected (filled in) briefly before going back to the unselected appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `[expanded]="step === 0"` is right but `MatExpansionPanel` has a behavior that seems to override and toggle the `expanded` attribute upon click on the `MatExpansionPanel`, which seems logical for an accordion.

The only solution I found in order to disable this behavior is by adding `[disabled]="true"` on each `<mat-expansion-panel>` element :

```html
<mat-expansion-panel id="panel2" [disabled]="true" [expanded]="step === 2">
```

Working StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ksqhqz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ExpansionPanel` behavior is overriding the radio button, you might want to just use radio buttons with a div that conditionally shows if the corresponding radio button is clicked.

Working StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pfpwaa?file=src/app/accordian/accordion.compnent.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).